# come up with a set of function such that the following equation holds

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How could one come up with $f_i$'s such that the following holds?
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x1,...xN) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i 
\end{align}

where x_i's are strictly positive reals. We have the restriction on f_i that f_i should change if x_i is changed! f_i should give different values for different values of x_i.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quite easy since there is no restriction to what the $f_i$ can be.  For example let $$f_1 (x_1 , ... , x_N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i$$ and $f_i (x_1 , ... , x_N) = 1$ for all $i=2,...,N$

ADDENDUM

I think I have one for you.. Let $f_1 = x_1$, and for the rest $i \geq 2$ let
$$ f_i ( x_1 , ... , x_N) = 1 + \frac{x_i}{\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} x_k} $$
For example the first few $i$ go as follows:
$$ f_1 = x_1 $$
$$ f_1 f_2 = x_1 \left(1 + \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) = x_1 + x_2$$
$$ f_1 f_2 f_3 = x_1 \left(1 + \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) \left(1 + \frac{x_3}{x_1 + x_2} \right) = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$
etc

Comment: Good point! my question wasn't well-posed! I have this restriction on f_i that I want f_i to change if x_i is changed! so f_i should give different values for different values of x_i (at east for most x_i values)

Comment: @erfaun I have one solution although please check if any error in my work..